# product/1 instead of product.php?id=1

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is not really a problem but a question.

I have this file that shows the product information when you go to `URL/product.php?id=1` How can I make it show the same when going to `URL/product/1`. `id` is a variable that changes.

Sorry, I have no clue how htaccess works, and how to rewrite..

Comment: There are literally _thousands_ of existing answers to this question alone here on SO. None of all those answers helped? Why not? What was wrong with all those answers? And why should it help if we write one more answer? Please do a bit of research before asking a question. Your topic is demonstrated in all tutorials, looking into the excellent documentation of apache's rewriting module provides good examples and you can simply start in the "Related" section to the right of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *internally rewrite* the request from `/product/1` to `/product.php?id=1`. On Apache, you need to do this with mod_rewrite. In `.htaccess` this would take the form of:

```
# We must enable the rewrite engine before using mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On

# Internally rewrite a request from "/product/1"
RewriteRule ^product/1$ /product.php?id=1 [L]
```

Note that this literally rewrites from `/product/1` to `/product.php?id=1` (as stated in the question) nothing else. And is *internal* to the server - the URL in the browser's address bar does not change.

The arguments to Apache directives are space separated:

1. `^product/1$` - The first argument (*pattern*) to the `RewriteRule` directive is a [regular expression (regex)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that matches against the URL-path (only) of the request. Note that in `.htaccess` this URL-path does not start with a slash, so the URL-path that is matched is `product/1` not `/product/1`, even though you are requesting `example.com/product/1`.
2. `/product.php?id=1` - The second argument (*substitution*) is the string that is substituted for the requested URL. ie. the target URL. This is an "ordinary" string, not a regex.
3. `[L]` - The third argument (*flags*) are additional options that can change how the `RewriteRule` directive behaves. The argument must be surrounded in square brackets and contains a comma separated list of flags. The `L` (or `last`) flag signifies this is the *last* directive in this round of processing. If this is the last directive in the file then the `L` flag is not required. If you omit the `L` flag then processing continues and the request could be further rewritten (if you have more directives). Another common flag is the `R` (or `redirect`) flag. This changes the *internal rewrite* into an *external redirect* (which sends a `Location` HTTP response header back to the client and results in the browser being externally redirected to the new URL - the URL in the browser's address bar changes).

*Additional Note:* In this instance, since you are requesting "product" and a file with that *basename* exists (in fact, that is the file you are rewriting to) you also need to make sure that `MultiViews` is disabled (it is by default). If MultiViews is enabled (some shared hosts enable this for some reason) then mod_negotiation will trigger an internal subrequest for `product.php` *before* your mod_rewrite directive gets to rewrite the request and this will be missing the `id` URL parameter. (Numerous rewriting issues on SO are caused by conflicts with MultiViews.) To disable `MultiViews`, you can include this at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

#### More generic

To make this more generic and rewrite `/product/<number>` to `/product.php?id=<number>`, where `<number>` is 1 or more digits, you can modify the regex (first argument) and create a *backreference* that you use in the *substitution* string (second argument). For example:

```
# Internally rewrite a request from "/product/<number>"
RewriteRule ^product/(\d+)$ /product.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This would rewrite a URL of the form `/product/123` to `/product.php?id=123`. Where `123` is 1 or more digits, denoted by the regex subpattern `\d+`. (`\d` is a shorthand character class and is the same as the marginally more verbose `[0-9]`. `+` is a *quantifier* that indicates 1 or more of the preceding pattern - in this case digits.) By surrounding this in parentheses, we create a *capturing group*, which we can refer to in the *substitution*. That's what the `$1` backreference is. `$1` is essentially a *variable* that contains whatever *value* the regex captured.

#### In summary:

```
# Disable MultiViews
Options -MultiViews

# We must enable the rewrite engine before using mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On

# Internally rewrite a request to "/product/<number>"
RewriteRule ^product/(\d+)$ /product.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule